# Polymer 2.0 nested iron-pages

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, iron-pages

I'm not very good with iron-pages and app-route so I will try and explain this the best I can.

I am building a web application with two main "apps" built into it - the regular user interface and an admin dashboard. So naturally I would want two different main 'paths': `/admin` and `/home`

The admin dashboard should have a drawer in it, where I can select from a list of 'categories' and upon selecting a category, load a specific view. Example `/admin/users` will load a view that will load a list of users. And upon clicking on an item on the list page, bring up a details section. Example `/admin/user/UserA`

Here is my structure so far. demo-app has iron-pages that holds the HomePage and AdminPage. AdminPage also has iron-pages that holds ListView and DetailView.

I can get to the admin page, but upon selecting from a list of 'categories', the route doesn't pick up. I'm basing my code off of the Shop Demo

**demo-app**

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<iron-media-query query="max-width: 767px" query-matches="{{smallScreen}}"></iron-media-query>

<app-header role="navigation" id="header" effects="waterfall" condenses reveals>
  <app-toolbar>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>

<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404">
  <!-- home view -->
  <demo-home name="home"></demo-home>

  <!-- admin view -->
  <demo-admin name="admin"></demo-admin>

  <shop-404-warning name="404"></shop-404-warning>
</iron-pages>
```

**demo-admin**

```
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/admin"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <h1>Admin</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/admin/users">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/bars">Bars</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/stepsheets">Stepsheets</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/events">Events</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>subroute: [[subroute]]</p>

    <iron-pages role="main" selected="{{subroute.path}}" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404">
      <demo-list name="list" route="{{subroute}}"></demo-list>
    </iron-pages>
  </template>
```

**demo-list**

```
<app-route
    route="[[route]]"
    pattern="/admin/:collection"
    data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>

<h1>Collection: [[routeData.collection]]</h1>
```

**EDIT**
I might be onto something...

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
<app-route
    route="{{subroute}}"
    pattern="/:category"
    data="{{subrouteData}}"></app-route>
```

and then

```
  static get observers() { return [
    '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
    '_routeCategoryChanged(subrouteData.category)'
  ]}
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it? I feel like this would get very cumbersome if I had a url with 3+ subroutes

**EDIT 2**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `demo-admin` the router

```
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/admin"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>
```

is probably not working as expected because `demo-app`'s `route` property is not accessible inside `demo-admin`. Also `patterm="/admin"` is redundant: if `demo-admin` is being loaded then the url is already `/admin`.

You can pass `demo-app`'s `subroute` property to child views who need to parse sub routes:

**demo-app.html**

```
<dom-module id="demo-app">
  <template>
    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}">
    </app-route>

    <iron-media-query query="max-width: 767px" query-matches="{{smallScreen}}"></iron-media-query>

    <app-header role="navigation" id="header" effects="waterfall" condenses reveals>
      <app-toolbar>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404">
      <demo-home name="home"></demo-home>
      <demo-admin name="admin" route="{{subroute}}"></demo-admin>
      <shop-404-warning name="404"></shop-404-warning>
    </iron-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    class DemoApp extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {
        return "demo-app";
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          page: {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            observer: '_pageChanged',
          },
          routeData: Object,
          subroute: Object,
        };
      }

      static get observers() {
        return [
          '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
        ];
      }

      _routePageChanged(page) {
        this.page = page || 'demo-home';
      }

      // Use this only if you want to lazy load pages
      _pageChanged(page) {
        const resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('demo-' + page + '.html');
        Polymer.importHref(
          resolvedPageUrl,
          null,
          this._showPage404.bind(this),
          true);
      }

      _showPage404() {
        this.page = '404';
      }

    }
    customElements.define(DemoApp.is, DemoApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**demo-admin.html**

```
<dom-module id="demo-admin">
  <template>
    <app-route
      route="{{route}}"
      pattern="/:category"
      data="{{routeData}}"
      tail="{{subroute}}">
    </app-route>

    <h1>Admin</h1>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="/admin/users">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/bars">Bars</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/stepsheets">Stepsheets</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/events">Events</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>subroute: [[subroute]]</p>

    <iron-pages
      role="main"selected="[[category]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404">
      <demo-list name="list" route="{{subroute}}"></demo-list>
      <!-- Other pages -->
    </iron-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    class DemoAdmin extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {
        return "demo-admin";
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          category: {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            observer: '_categoryChanged',
          },
          routeData: Object,
          subroute: Object,
        };
      }

      static get observers() {
        return [
          '_routeCategoryChanged(routeData.category)',
        ];
      }

      _routeCategoryChanged(page) {
        this.page = page || 'defaultPage';
      }

      _categoryChanged(page) {
        const resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('demo-' + page + '.html');
        Polymer.importHref(
          resolvedPageUrl,
          null,
          this._showPage404.bind(this),
          true);
      }

      _showPage404() {
        this.page = '404';
      }

    }
    customElements.define(DemoAdmin.is, DemoAdmin);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Find more info in `app-route`'s [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route).

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately it's still not working. Should I be handling the page changes in demo-app? I can't get my subpage to propagate back to the demo-app. Example: /admin/users doesn't do anything but /users changes the page, but to a 404. Because my app-route pattern in demo-app is set to pattern="/:page" (I think)

Comment: In demo-app you just need to handle the first path component (ie "/admin") and pass its tail to subviews who will parse the next components. I updated the answer because I took for granted all the observers part (which probably you are already using in demo-app for `page` property) like in the [polymer starter kit](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-starter-kit/blob/1e0eeed895c683a0fd801ec69fad1d4fc4f5799f/src/my-app.html#L114). `routeData.category` instead of `category` will update automatically `iron-pages` active view. Also, are you lazy loading `demo-list` or other sub views?

Comment: I updated to `routeData.category` and that seemed to take care of the 404 issue, but it did not propagate back to demo-app. I have an observer in demo-app: `_routePageChanged(routeData.page)`, but that only will look for /admin like you said. Would I setup an observer on the demo-admin page? I can observe the 'category' i.e. /admin/users - but again, gotta pass that back to demo-app (i think?) Stupid question - how bad is it to just observe `route` in demo-app? Thanks!

Comment: I expanded a bit the code samples in the answer to show a more complete implementation which I tried locally and seems to work fine. I still don't get what "pass back to demo-app" means. Of course if you prefer you can observe as many levels of nested routes as you want in `demo-app` although passing tails to child views can be more handy and modular.

Comment: Ok. This is starting to make a lot more sense. I don't know why I was under the impression that all the page routing was done in `demo-app`. That's what I meant by "pass back to demo-app". Silly me. I believe it's working - but now I have both pages showing. The `iron-page` in `demo-app` isn't getting replaced by the one in `demo-admin` - I provided a screenshot.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtclv.jpg) is what, I think, is happening in your screenshot. If you don't want the card at the top you can easily remove it from `demo-admin`'s template. Or you want the whole drawer and toolbar layout to be inside `demo-admin`? In that case you just need to move the code from one page to the other one. `demo-app` can also be a big full-page `iron-pages` element.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I think I [almost] have it. I can take it from here haha